# Difference between "Num Docs" and "Max Doc" in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj

Can someone let me know what is the difference between `Num Docs` and `Max Doc` reported in Solr Admin?

I am seeing this difference in value after executing [deleteByQuery](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html#deleteByQuery-java.lang.String-) from SolrJ. I am using Solr 5.2.1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max Doc indicates the count of document that exist before the update(delete).documents that existed in your index before update started(delete started)

Num Docs is the new count after the update i.e. the current count.

In your case you have delete operation where it deleted 2 documents.

And I guess you must be using DIH....where DIH deletes all docs and add them new again. and after DIH commits it will keep the new one and delete the older ones.

Comment: -  I am using `deleteByQuery` from SolrJ. I have posted the link of the api in my question. Can you let me know what are the consequence if both the counts are not equal? How to make both of them equal? Will there be any impact when I execute a search query now in this state ?

Comment: both the counts will be equal when your deletebyQuery will not find anything to be deleted.  Your search query will not find the docs which are deleted (if they are deleted by the deleteByQuery). Both the counts will not be equal if your deleteByQuery deletes something which is the current case..